# Edit and save file

Tags: python, file

I need to edit my file and save it so that I can use it for another program  . First I need to put "," in between every word and add a word at the end of every line.

In order to put "," in between every word , I used this command

```
for line in open('myfile','r+') :
    for word in line.split():
        new = ",".join(map(str,word)) 
        print new
```

I'm not too sure how to overwrite the original file or maybe create a new output file for the edited version . I tried something like this

```
with open('myfile','r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
             new = ",".join(map(str,word)) 
             f.write(new)
```

The output is not what i wanted (different from the print new) . 
Second, I need to add a word at the end of every line. So, i tried this

```
source = open('myfile','r')
output = open('out','a')
output.write(source.read().replace("\n", "yes\n"))
```

The code to add new word works perfectly. But I was thinking there should be an easier way to open a file , do two editing in one go and save it. But I'm not too sure how. Ive spent a tremendous amount of time to figure out how to overwrite the file and it's about time I seek for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
source = open('myfile', 'r')
output = open('out','w')
output.write('yes\n'.join(','.join(line.split()) for line in source.read().split('\n')))
```

One-liner:

```
open('out', 'w').write('yes\n'.join(','.join(line.split() for line in open('myfile', 'r').read().split('\n')))
```

Or more legibly:

```
source = open('myfile', 'r')
processed_lines = []
for line in source:
    line = ','.join(line.split()).replace('\n', 'yes\n')
    processed_lines.append(line)
output = open('out', 'w')
output.write(''.join(processed_lines))
```

**EDIT**
Apparently I misread everything, lol.

```
#It looks like you are writing the word yes to all of the lines, then spliting
#each word into letters and listing those word's letters on their own line? 
source = open('myfile','r')
output = open('out','w')
for line in source:
    for word in line.split():
        new = ",".join(word)
        print >>output, new
    print >>output, 'y,e,s'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but none of the code that you gave me works for me. All of them don't produce output with "," in between every word. They only produced output with 'yes' added at the end of every line. So basically the output is the same as my working third code.

Comment: actually the code you provided earlier worked perfectly after I get rid the .split and just use join(line) .

Answer (score 0):

How big is this file?
Maybe You could create a temporary list which would just contain everything from file you want to edit. Every element could represent one line.
Editing list of strings is pretty simple.
After Your changes you can just open Your file again with

```
writable = open('configuration', 'w')
```

and then put changed lines to file with

```
file.write(writable, currentLine + '\n')
```

.
Hope that helps - even a little bit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you could read all the lines in f before overwriting f, assuming f is opened in 'r+' mode.  Append all the results into a string, then execute:

```
f.seek(0)    # reset file pointer back to start of file
f.write(new) # new should contain all concatenated lines
f.truncate() # get rid of any extra stuff from the old file
f.close()
```

For the second problem, the solution is similar: Read the entire file, make your edits, call f.seek(0), write the contents, f.truncate() and f.close().

Comment: my second code i.e. to add new word at every line and save the file works perfectly. But i want to do adding "," in between every word followed by adding a new word at the end of every file without having to open and close the file twice.

Comment: You could do something like `source=open('myfile', 'r+') txt=source.read().replace("\n", "yes\n") source.seek(0) source.write(txt) source.truncate() source.close()`.